# Android - upload data to mysql db and without internet - save to buffer

Tags: android, mysql, database

please help me. I want program for android.

Mobile - (TEXT DATA) =>
save data to buffer in mobile =>
if internet state = online => Buffer send his data to MySQL db

I've got a horrible English, sorry :-(

Please give me any full example or even source code how to because I am only beginner.

Thank you so much <3

Comment: Rather than horrible English, I see horrible problem statement/no clear question at all. At the least, you need to provide SO with what you have done so far, and where you are stuck. No-one will do your homework/work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116810/ios-store-and-forward-framework-for-offline-http-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you links because you are a beginner you must have good understanding what you doing.

**First you need to implement connection monitoring in your app**

Check this link
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineConnection

**Then save your data to `SharedPreferences`**

Check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

With combination of above both solution you will be able to achieve your task.

Thank you.